# Blank Chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wrote this code to generate a bar chart in Rstudio and it returned a blank chart. It's the first time this has happened to me and I've restarted rstudio and same result. Is there an issue with my code or any other way to get what I need?

```
  WorldCupMatches %>% 
  filter(Home.Team.Initials %in% c(top10teams) ) %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = Home.Team.Initials, y = Attendance)) +
   geom_col()
```

Comment: @akrun sorry about that i forgot to include the vector. I just updated the original post but i can post the updated code here if you'd like?

Comment: Try without the filter. I think you can remove the `c()` function, simply refer to your top10teams variable. Make sure your variable has data! Inspect your data by temporarily piping the filtered data to `view()`.

Comment: @akrun im sorry, im still kind of new to R. Im not really following that last explanation. I tried taking out the filter and ran it and got an error. I also tried taking out the c() function and adding the filter back in and another error. Is there another way to explain it. Im sorry to bother

Comment: Try this line: `filter(Home.Team.Initials %in% top10teams) %>% View()` and make sure your data filtered correct, then remove the `View()` and see if the plot works.

Comment: @M.Viking gotcha thanks for the help the chart is working now! Sorry again for all the noob questions